# cumulative count python backwards

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe as below

```
ID       count
1          10
2          20
3          40
```

So for the cumulative count, I want to achieve

```
ID       count     cum Count
1          10         70
2          20         50 
3          40         40
```

Any idea how to do this with pandas?

Comment: Is output correct? `50` not `60` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use double `[::-1]` for swap order:

```
df['cum Count'] = df['count'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
print (df)
   ID  count  cum Count
0   1     10         70
1   2     20         60
2   3     40         40
```

Numpy solution:

```
df['cum Count'] = df['count'].values[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
print (df)
   ID  count  cum Count
0   1     10         70
1   2     20         60
2   3     40         40
```